# Expanding div to scroll height

Tags: jquery

I need to expand a div that has overflow set to hidden via css. When clicking on «expand» the hight of the div is expanded to the hight necessary to display the whole text. To achieve this, I use this code:

```
$( ".expand" ).click(function() {
$('#mainDiv').animate({
height: $('#mainDiv').get(0).scrollHeight
}, 500, function(){
$(this).height('auto');
});
});
```

This works as expected with a hard coded paragraph like this:

```
<p class="expand">Expand …</p>
```

Now I'd like to insert this paragraph dynamically depending on whether the text in the div is longer than fits the div or not. If it is smaller than the divs set height, there is no need for this paragraph. So I tried to achieve this by adding a function so as the code now looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var height = $('#mainDiv').prop('scrollHeight');
if(height>420){
$("<p class='expand'>Expand …</p>").insertAfter('#mainDiv');
}
});

$( ".aufklappen" ).click(function() {
$('#hauptTextInhaltReduziert').animate({
height: $('#hauptTextInhaltReduziert').get(0).scrollHeight
}, 500, function(){
$(this).height('auto');
});
});
```

That inserts the paragraph alright. BUT: it doesn't work, nothing happens when clicking on the paragraph.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

your code does not cover DOM changes. Use the following:

```
$( ".aufklappen" ).on("click", function() {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegated event handler bound to the container/body:

try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.aufklappen', function(){
  $('#hauptTextInhaltReduziert').animate({
    height: $('#hauptTextInhaltReduziert').get(0).scrollHeight
   }, 500, function(){
   $(this).height('auto');
  });
});
```

That is, bind to an element that exists at the moment that the JS runs (body exists when the page loads), and supply a selector in the second parameter to .on(). When a click occurs on `body` element jQuery checks whether it applied to a child of that element which matches `.aufklappen` the selector.

Comment: Thank you very much Anuj. This did the trick. You safed my day!