# Using jquery to hide and show div element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a woocommerce product page - here is the link - http://icestartup.com/testsites/ujsnkfvs22/wordpress/product/2-door-wardrobe/

This is a woocommerce product page.

In that page I am trying to hide and show a div tag when I am changing the select menu called "Pick Your Laminate".

Here is the code I used - 
Note that "pick-your-laminate" is the id of the select tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pick-your-laminate").change(function(){
        if($(this).children("option").attr(":selected")=="Plain Laminate"){
            $(".box").not(".plain").hide();
            $(".plain").show();
        }
        if($(this).children("option").attr(":selected")=="Digital Laminate"){
            $(".box").not(".digital").hide();
            $(".digital").show();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This did not work. I mean, nothing happened at all when i changed the select menu options. So I made the code more simple and i just thought I will make an alert box display when I change the dropdown menu. Heres the new code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pick-your-laminate").change(function(){
       alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    });
});
</script>
```

Still NOTHING HAPPENED.

What is going on? Can you guys find the problem?

You can verify by inspecting the webpage where the code is placed, that will be too nice.

[Link here](http://icestartup.com/testsites/ujsnkfvs22/wordpress/product/2-door-wardrobe/)

Comment: That's not the correct DOM ready handler for Wordpress, you have to use `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...`

Comment: @mplungjan - why ?

Comment: @mplungjan - Wordpress is in NoConflict mode by default ?

Comment: @mplungjan That duplicate is wrong.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes because `$("#id").val()` will work here, and is what should be used. In that question it's because the options don't have a `value` attribute.

Comment: Here's how it *should* look -> https://jsfiddle.net/hq0bgruq/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - the duplicate shows both. I have now checked OPs site and .val() can indeed be used as can the .text()

Comment: @adeneo - ok, that is possible that WP would benefit, but `console.log($.fn.jquery)` shows the correct jQuery version so it is loaded and active

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think you understand my point. The entire purpose of that question is why `.val()` cannot be used on the `select`. Making this a duplicate makes the same assumption and would be misinforming users.

Comment: @mplungjan - that's great, now explain why the second code snippet with just the alert doesn't work, and in the OP's site it's even `$('select').change...` and still doesn't fire an alert.

Comment: @adeneo It works fine with just the select and the snippet of JS used. So something must be interfering with it (probally Wordpress as you said), or they are using a cached version when they tested it. But yes the user needs to make a snippet/fiddle to produce the problem

Comment: There is indeed something interfering with the selects. Perhaps some pretty select or similar. I have reopened the question.

Comment: Don't think this will solve your issue but if your option values match your div classes, you can make the showing and hiding quite a bit simpler. https://jsfiddle.net/1byxtm9k/

Comment: Heavy page does something to the DOM. This works but is not a solution: `setTimeout(function() {
   $("#height").on("change",function(){console.log("yes")})
},3000)`

Comment: @mplungjan - it works if one runs the OP's code again in the console as well, it just doesn't work when the page first load, so the elements are probably changed or moved somehow during pageload.

Comment: Guys I am trapped. Infact if I use .click instead of .change its working. Is there something I can do like using javascript without jquery or something?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I did not understand why $("this").value is working and not $(this).children("option").attr(":selected"). Can you explain this clearly if possible?

Comment: @Adam Basically `$('#mySelect').val()` is the standard way to get the value of a selected element in jQuery. What it looks like you are trying to do is get the element with the `selected` attribute. As in it must have `<option ... selected ... >`, although that code would still not work even in that case. The `.attr()` method only accesses the first element, and along with that doesn't support getting `selected`. Instead you would want to do: `$('#mySelect').children("option:selected").val()`, but again it would be better to just do `$('#mySelect').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

[find more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027771/expanding-div-to-scroll-height/38027838#38027838)

try this:

```
$("body").on('change', '#pick-your-laminate', function(){
    if($(this).children("option").attr(":selected")=="Plain Laminate"){
        $(".box").not(".plain").hide();
        $(".plain").show();
    }
    if($(this).children("option").attr(":selected")=="Digital Laminate"){
        $(".box").not(".digital").hide();
        $(".digital").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: No, the problem is they need to use `$(this).val()` to get the selected item. Unless they explicitly defined a `selected` attribute in one of the options it will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes according to what is told  by Spencer Wieczorek and mplungjan. What i did was that i used some delay using settimeout function in javascript and the jquery code needed a change as well.

Now it is working. You can check the link - [LINK](http://icestartup.com/testsites/ujsnkfvs22/wordpress/product/2-door-wardrobe/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("#pick-your-laminate").on('change', function(){
                    if ( this.value == "Plain Laminate" ) {
                        $(".box").not(".plain").hide();
                        $(".plain").show();
                    } else if ( this.value == "Digital Laminate" ) {
                        $(".box").not(".digital").hide();
                        $(".digital").show();
                    }
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
```

I dont think this is an elegant solution.
Do you guys have any idea why I should use a delay? Is there an alternative piece of code?