# LocalStorage not saving onclick attributes

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to make a calendar web application and want to save a users' state using localstorage. I have tried using two methods (innerHTML as well as a javascript DOM-to-JSON; https://github.com/azaslavsky/domJSON), but each removes the button's onclick event.

I believe the problem is that it is stringifying only the innerhtml, which for some reason doesnt have my onlick event listed (although the onlick event fires). What should I do so that a user can reload the page and still use the buttons.

Here is an example that shows the button stop working (delete cache and website cookies/data to make the button work again):
https://codepen.io/samuel-solomon/pen/XWdzKjd?editors=1011

```
window.pageState;

$(document).ready(function(){
  let div = document.getElementById("div")
  
  window.pageState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pageState'));
  if (window.pageState === null) {
    let btn = document.createElement('button')
    btn.innerText = "Hello";
    btn.style = "height: 100px";
    btn.onclick = function (btn) {change_text(btn)}.bind(null, btn);
    div.appendChild(btn);
    window.pageState = {state: div.innerHTML};
  }
  else {div.innerHTML = window.pageState.state}
});

function change_text(btn) {
  let div = document.getElementById("div");
  if (btn.innerText === "Hello") {btn.innerText = "Goodbye";}
  else if (btn.innerText === "Goodbye") {btn.innerText = "Hello";}
  localStorage.setItem('pageState', JSON.stringify(window.pageState));
}
```

Here is my wbesite where the problem exists (Ex: double click 'Ae 101A' and double click it in the calender. it should disappear. Now add it again and reload the page. Now it doesnt disappear on double click):
https://turtle-pond.com/

Comment: So you want to save the data in the localStorage whatever the user selected right ?

Comment: Just want to know why are you using DOMtoJson, might be the thing you are trying to achieve can be achieved by some other way as well

Comment: Yes, I can also just save the .innerHTML. The problem is the innerHTML for some reason saves the styling, but not the onclick even though they are both added the same way.

Comment: If you go to my website (https://turtle-pond.com/) you can see that indeed the styling is great, but when you inspect the element, the onclick doesnt appear

Comment: Like onclick where in the DOM you are looking for?

Comment: If you look at the codepen, all I am doing is using the getElementById and trying to store it in a localStorage. The onclick is already assigned to the DOM object (like the style), but only the style stores

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using jQuery. For hooking events to dynamically created elements, I suggest the selector filtering approach: instead of binding the click event on the button element itself, listen for the click event on the parent container (or even the document) and filter by the button's selector. Here is how:

```
window.pageState;

$(document).ready(function(){
  let div = document.getElementById("div")

  $(document).on('click', "#my-button", function (event) {
    const btn = event.target; // or btn = document.getElementById("my-button");
    change_text(btn);
  }); 
  
  window.pageState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pageState'));
  if (window.pageState === null) {
    let btn = document.createElement('button')
    btn.innerText = "Hello";
    btn.style = "height: 100px";
    btn.id = "my-button";
    div.appendChild(btn);
    window.pageState = {state: div.innerHTML};
  }
  else {div.innerHTML = window.pageState.state}
});

function change_text(btn) {
  let div = document.getElementById("div");
  if (btn.innerText === "Hello") {btn.innerText = "Goodbye";}
  else if (btn.innerText === "Goodbye") {btn.innerText = "Hello";}
  localStorage.setItem('pageState', JSON.stringify(window.pageState));
}
```

Read more about this [on jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314782/jquery-click-filter-on-button-elements).

Comment: Thank you for the response. It seems you are just reassigning the button's onclikc everytime. If you move the onlick assignment into the first if statement it no long works. I need the button's onlick to only be assigned once when the user adds the event to the calender. After that I should store it in the localStorage. Is there a way the code could do this?

Comment: The button no longer has a onclick event on it. Clicking on the document will filter the selector and call the handler only if the target matches the selector. This way, if there is a button with id `my-button`, the `change_text` function is called. If the button is not present, nothing happens.